# Latest updates, but only one per polymorphic object using GROUP

Tags: sql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have three models:

```
class Update
  attr_accessible :object_id, :object_type

  belongs_to :object, :polymorphic

  default_scope order('created_at DESC')
end

class Document
  has_many :updates, as: :object
end

class Report
  has_many :updates, as: :object
end
```

Now, using sql or the Active Record query interface I want to be able to grab pick out the lastest Update for each object.

I was thinking that I would do something like this:

```
Update.group(:object_id).group(:object_type)
```

That does indeed give me only one update per object, but it is not always the latest update and I am not sure why.

Does group just select a random record from the group? Is there a simple way to ensure that the latest update gets selected?